# Whats wrong with make file

Tags: makefile

i am trying to make makefile compile object files in to `obj` dir and then link the compiled code and turn it in to executable here is it is

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Iinclude.
OBJ = obj/main.o obj/print.o

%.o: %.c 
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

prog: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

and the error is No rule to make target 'obj/main.o', needed by 'prog'.  Stop.
this is a pure copy paste that i have done from makefile tutorial just to make sure it doesnt work as well.

So why doesnt this line work

```
%.o: %.c 
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

Comment: Quite obviously, you state that `obj/main.o` could be built from `obj/main.c`, but you don't have the latter.

Comment: @Matt latter ? which latter ?

Comment: you don't have `obj/main.c`, so the recipe is not applicable.

Comment: @Matt .o: %.c 
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)   <- what is this then ? this is a rule to make object files

Comment: @Matt this why ia m askign why does this rule doesn't work

Comment: Check in your `obj` directory.  Is there a `obj/main.c` source file there?

Comment: %.c replace just extension but obj/filename stays as make look for it in obj directory. So you should use -o obj/$@ etc, and OBJ without obj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rule of this kind ...

```
%.o: %.c 
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

is perfectly fine (with GNU make -- not so much with other `make` implementations).  It builds a `.o` file from the corresponding `.c` file, where "corresponding" means having a name formed by changing the trailing `.o` to `.c`.  This isn't actually needful, though, because `make` has a built-in rule that does substantially the same thing.

The message

> > No rule to make target 'obj/main.o', needed by 'prog'. Stop.

Identifies `obj/main.o` as a prerequisite needed by target `prog` that does not exist and for which there is no [applicable] rule.  The pattern rule above would be applicable if there were a corresponding source (in the sense described above), but evidently there isn't.

To be absolutely clear: the corresponding source formed by replacing the `.o` in `obj/main.o` with `.c` is `obj/main.c`.  Unless such a file exists, the pattern rule you present is not applicable for building `obj/main.o`.  The `make` program itself doesn't really know or care about directories.  The commands it executes do, but to `make` itself, target and prerequisite identifiers are just flat sequences of characters.

My first recommendation for such things is to stop trying to be cute.  It is simplest and most common to build object files in the same directory as their sources.  Supposing that your C sources are in a `src/` subdirectory relative to the makefile, this makefile would suffice for that (relying on the built in .c.o rule):

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Iinclude.

prog: src/main.o src/print.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

But if you insist on compiling objects to a separate directory, then your pattern rule needs to reflect that:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Iinclude.
OBJ = obj/main.o obj/print.o

obj/%.o: src/%.c 
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

prog: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

Comment: thanks so much man that did clarify everything for me. very helpfull answer